# How to rename multiple hdfs file to some other file name with sequence number and then move it to another location

Tags: python, bash, pyspark, hdfs, airflow

```
hdfs dfs -ls user/unknown_test_11
-rw-r--r--   3 svcusprd hdfs            0 2022-01-20 08:14 user/unknown_test_11/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   3 svcusprd hdfs 727288997334 2022-01-20 08:14 user/unknown_test_11/part-00000-961a93d9-45f2-43fd-b594-cd6f2b690e6f-c000.csv
-rw-r--r--   3 svcusprd hdfs    401558518 2022-01-20 07:11 user/unknown_test_11/part-00001-961a93d9-45f2-43fd-b594-cd6f2b690e6f-c000.csv
-rw-r--r--   3 svcusprd hdfs    683031614 2022-01-20 07:10 user/unknown_test_11/part-00002-961a93d9-45f2-43fd-b594-cd6f2b690e6f-c000.csv
-rw-r--r--   3 svcusprd hdfs    693199661 2022-01-20 07:12 user/unknown_test_11/part-00003-961a93d9-45f2-43fd-b594-cd6f2b690e6f-c000.csv
```

to

```
test-001.csv
test-002.csv
test-003.csv
test-004.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming newpath exists. Otherwise create it first by hand or with `os.mkdir`.

```
import os


oldpath= r'path_to_old_folder'
newpath= r'path_to_new_folder'

files = os.listdir(oldpath)

cnt = 0
for i in files:
    if i.endswith('csv'):
        cnt += 1
        newfilename = 'test-' + (str(cnt).zfill(3)) + '.csv'
        os.rename(os.path.join(oldpath, i), os.path.join(newpath, newfilename))
```

Comment: Actually, I want either by bash scripting or by any command, so that it can work in airflow also

Comment: will this take hdfs dfs -ls path?

Comment: I don't know what you are meaning with 'by bash scripting'. My solution is a pure pythonic one. Please provide more information: What do you excactly want, what have you done so far and what are the issues and struggles?

Comment: Hi @EndorCartographer
I want to copy the file from hdfs location to some other locations & rename those csv files with sequentially number added & current date should be added while renaming to each files in pyspark

Comment: I see. So it is is a hadoop thing. You can use `subprocess` to use `hdfs`commands with python: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html
Regrettably I don't have a hadoop server, so I cannot provide a tested, reproducible solution.